# Minimal polynomial of the matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, minimal-polynomials

Recently I've encountered the following problem

> Find minimal polynomial of $A =\begin{pmatrix}
> 2 & 3 & 4\\
> 0 & 2 & 0 \\
> 0 & 0 & 2
> \end{pmatrix}$ in $\mathbb{R}[x]$

Firstly, we can compute the characteristic polynomial which is obviously $c = (x - 2)^3$, then we know that the minimal polynomial is the one which divides $c$ and has the minimal degree. Straightforward computation yields that $m_A = (x - 2)^2$. And it makes sense, except the fact that minimal polynomial should be irreducible, and here there are two factors. Am I missing anything?

Comment: The minimal polynomial of a matrix needs not be irreducible.

Answer (score 1):

**Note:** You might be conflating *matrix minimal polynomial* ([linear algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimal_polynomial_(linear_algebra)), [square matrix $K$-algebras](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_ring#Minimal_polynomial)) and *minimal polynomial of an element in a field extension* ([field theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimal_polynomial_(field_theory))). The latter is [always irreducible](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimal_polynomial_(field_theory)#Properties) (the key is that the overfield is also an [integral domain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_domain)), but the former doesn't have to be (a $K$-algebra may not be an integral domain).

Comment: But why is it so, as we can view vector space as field extension?

Comment: No. The general concept for which the minimal polynomial is defined is $K$-algebra, let's call it $L$ (with $K$ field). If $L$ is also a field, then the MP is irreducible. If $L$ is a $K$-algebra of square matrices, then MP does not have to be irreducible.

Answer (score 0):

The minimal polynomial only has to be irreducible in the *scalar* setting; $m_A=(x-2)^2$ is perfectly right.

Comment: You mean scalar setting is $\mathbb{R}[x]$ in this case?

Comment: @Squidward Yes.

Comment: So $(x - 2)^2$ is viewed as a constant in $\mathbb{R}[x]$, then can you please provide any example of reducible polynomial in this scalar setting. Maybe $(y - (x - 2))(y + (x - 2))$ works?